Testing Flutter Apps on iOS Devices Using Windows
I'm new to developing mobile applications with Flutter, and I'm currently building a mobile app on a Windows machine. I can already test my apps on Android devices without any issues. However, I have a few questions about testing on iOS devices:

Can my code run directly on an iOS mobile device?
Do I need to have an iPhone to test my app on iOS?
Is it possible to test my app using my Windows laptop?

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I was considering buying an iPhone to use for testing. However, iPhones are quite expensive here in Brazil, and I'm not sure if I will be able to test the app effectively by connecting the iPhone to my Windows laptop.

Buying an iPhone wouldn't be enough, as you need to compile the Flutter code into an iOS app - and the tooling required for that (Xcode) is only available for macOS.


You will need a Mac OS to test your flutter app for ios. Building for ios requires Xcode which is only supported for Mac OS.
You can use an iOS emulator or physical device for testing
You can test for andriod/web on a windows device, but will need a Mac OS for Apple Devices

